# Which functional annotations could be useful?

Tags: genomics, genetics

Analyzing a genome, for a generic gene, which functional annotations (e.g from Gene Ontology) can help understanding its meaning/function or, at least, provide helpful informations?

- Annotations of that gene
- Annotations of orthologous genes (?)
- Annotations of paralogous genes (?)
- Co-expressed genes (given a biological condition) (?)
- What else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I'd add genetic effects of the gene and its orthologs in that own
  host. Knockouts and overexpression are powerful in uncovering
  function.
- In terms of baseline or normal expression, I would add    tissue,
  developmental or differentiation time points, and conditions which stimulate or repress expression.